# Complex soap_header xml objects for ruby savon gem

Tags: ruby, xml, wsdl, savon

Working on a project with this WSDL: http://developer.ebay.com/webservices/latest/ebaysvc.wsdl

```
$client = Savon.client(

:wsdl => "http://developer.ebay.com/webservices/latest/ebaysvc.wsdl",
:endpoint => "https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/wsapi?callname=AddItem&siteid=0&version=733& Routing=new",
:headers => { "Content-Type" => "application/soap+xml", "SOAPAction" => "AddItemRequest"},
:namespace => "urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents",
:soap_header => { CREDENTIALS GO HERE: SEE BELOW }
)
```

What I need is a complex type xml format. Where the first part of soap_header is RequestCredentials and has several child nodes, and one of those (Credentials) has 3 child nodes... I also need to escape the lower camel case and just use camel case.

The final result with the xml output should look something like:

```
<urn:RequestCredentials>
  <urn:eBayAuthToken>
  AUTH TOKEN HERE
  </urn:eBayAuthToken>
  <urn:Credentials>
    <urn:DevId>DEVID HERE</urn:DevId>
    ect..... (two more child nodes (AppId, and AuthCert)
  </urn:Credentials>
</urn:RequestCredentials>
```

Here is the error I receive:
14007
     Error
     SOAP Authentication failed due to missing or invalid security header.

Any ideas on how to correctly format the xml with the savon gem?